# Watin : Get DropDown list

Tags: c#, watin

I'm trying to get a list from a dropdown,since it's not a selectlist i've tried something like this

```
   this.ContextBrowser.Link(new Regex("ddlSQuestion1_Arrow")).Click();
   this.ContextBrowser.Div(Find.ByText(new Regex("What is the name of the first school you attended?"))).Click();
```

What the code is actually doing is clicking on the dropdown arrow, manage to pull down the list but i can;t click on the list aka **li**.How can i click on the dropdown list.Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a hint: "new Regex" and then passing a string with a "?" inside seems to me as if you should escape the reserved "?" character.

Comment: i'm able to get the elements;using quickwatch these items exits;But i'm unable to click on "What is the name of the first school you attended?" list.are you saying that because of the "?" this symbol(probably a special symbol) watin was not able to click on it?or should i look at a different way to do this?Dropdown is not supported by watin is there any other way i can do this?

Comment: Hello, Can you show use the HTML you have ? According to your code, is it something like <a id="ddlSQuestion1_Arrow"></a> and <div>What is the name of the first school you attended?</div>. But having something more precise could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get the elements inside the dropdown list like so

```
var select = this.ContextBrowser.Link(new Regex("ddlSQuestion1_Arrow")).Element[2];
select.click();
```

Hope this help